# Does windows 7 disk manager mirror disk or partitions?

Tags: windows-7, raid, software-raid, raid-1, disk-management

My servers Raid 1 disappeared when I did a bios update, And now in order to get it back I have to format my 2 * 3tb hard drives. Which isnt really a solution for me.

So I have desiced to try and make a software raid in windows 7 professional.

I am stuck on something now though.

If I right click on Disk0 then `New Mirrored volume` is greyed out.  But I can right click on a partition and i get the option to `Add Mirror..`  Which do I want to do?

I am heading towards wanting a Mirrored Disk not just a partition. How can I un grey the option?

Even better would be how can I recover my motherboard raid? After the bios update, but disks appeared int eh cntrol+i menu seperately and there was no Raid Volume anymore? I can create a new raid volume but it then says it will delete all the data on this disk?

[image: bla]
[image: bla]
[image: bla]

Answer (score 2):

A Dynamic Disk’s special features work on the partition level. This is by design and nothing can be done about it. Still, it may be a better (as in “more predictable”) solution than your motherboards FakeRAID.

If you really need your system to be available (that’s what RAID does, it’s not backup), go for a real hardware RAID controller. Just check the maximum disk size, some older/cheaper ones are still limited to 2 TB.

#### Update

Your disk is full, so you can’t create new partitions, that is what “**New** mirrored **volume**” does. You can, however, add mirrors to existing partitions, like you noticed. This is what you want. Like I said, you can’t mirror a disk.If you want all partitions to be mirrored, you need to manually add mirrors to all partitions.

Comment: Unfortunately price does come into play, and that would indeed require a reformat.

Comment: This doesn't really answer the question for the user, as he still needs to wipe his data

Comment: If he wants to have another go at FakeRAID, yes. That cannot be avoided. I absolutely cannot recommend it anyway. Intel’s onboard RAID destroyed 500 GB (RAID 5) of precious data because of a lame software error. Don’t use it, ever. Seriously. He’s off way better with Dynamic Disks.

Comment: @DanielB OK but I cant do dynamic disk at the moment as create mirror array is grey out. How can I do this? because I dont just want to mirror a partition I want to mirror the entire disk. So if one crashes my server can continue running windows. I appreciate you advice, and i have read it every where on the net. DONT USE FAKE RAID. I dont know why intel invests to much time into putting it on thier boards then?

Comment: @Zapnologica Please see the updated answer. I also don’ṯ think some cheap software RAID is that much of an effort to Intel or anyone. It’s simply another selling point.

Comment: @DanielB So if I just add a mirror to every partition it will essentially be the same as mirroring the disks? Will the 2nd still boot then? as I dont believe its mbr etc will be synced?

Comment: Dunno. The boot partition (the 100 MB thingy) doesn’t appear to be a “Dynamic Partition”, so I guess not. The OS itself would still be there, though. Creating another boot loader is trivial with the `bcdboot` command, but I don’t know how to create a partition like this on a Dynamic Disk.

Comment: So I should probably let all the partitions sync, the remove disk 0 create the mbr for disk1 check it boots then plug both back in?